# How do I get importer file name in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For logging setup in a utility script, it would be useful to set the log filename to the name of the **importing** module:

foo.py:

```
import bar

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar.setup_logging()
```

bar.py:

```
def setup_logging():
    [...]
    logging.basicConfig(filename=???, [...])
```

Calling `foo.py` should print `foo` (or `foo.py`).

Comment: Are you able to pass arguments when calling `setup_logging`?

Comment: Yes, but we'd like to avoid duplicating code if we can...

Answer (score 4):

```
frm = inspect.stack()[1]
#Now, frm contains a tuple of frame object, code path, code line etc...
mod = inspect.getmodule(frm[0])
#pass the frame object to get the module object and print its name prop
print '[%s] %s' % (mod.__name__, msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

[@MadhavanKumar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27355806/96588) was on the right track:

```
$ cat lib/bar.py
def setup_logging():
    print os.path.basename(inspect.stack()[1][1])
$ python lib/foo.py
foo
```